# Tag synonym request: [awtrobot] -> [awt.robot]

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I suggested a tag wiki excerpt for [awtrobot](/questions/tagged/awtrobot) and one of the reviewers [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128551) it would probably be better off as [awt-robot](/questions/tagged/awt-robot). <s>I happened to agree— it should really be hyphenated.</s> *Edit: Actually it should probably go into [awt.robot](/questions/tagged/awt.robot). At the time I asked this question I guess I was under the impression that hyphens were the only punctuation allowed in tags.*

<s>[awt-robot](/questions/tagged/awt-robot)</s> [awt.robot](/questions/tagged/awt.robot) currently is unused, and [awtrobot](/questions/tagged/awtrobot) has 35 questions (a good number of which I retagged from [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+robot)).

So I suggest merging [awtrobot](/questions/tagged/awtrobot) -> <s>[awt-robot](/questions/tagged/awt-robot)</s> [awt.robot](/questions/tagged/awt.robot).

Comment: What's up with the Dot? I see that at some tags lately?

Comment: @Asylum The AWT Robot package name is `java.awt.robot`, so it seems more fitting somehow. Not entirely sure it matters much whether it's a dot or hyphen, just thinking it shouldn't be simply [awtrobot].